# How can I implement user sessions with android app and node server?

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, session, okhttp

I've built an android app and it can connect to my node express server just fine. However I don't know how to implement user sessions so that when users 'post' or 'get' from my server, my server can find which user it is.

My previous experience was with a simple website, where I used express-sessions, and the attached username to the session was used to search the MySql database and find the relevant information about the user.

I'm currently using OkHTTP3 in my app for connections.

Is there a simple idea to make this work?

Comment: I am not familiar on how express-sessions works but assuming it uses cookie so from the OkHttp3 point of view you should consider to use a cookie store otherwise all the sessions thing won't work: https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar

Comment: express session will not work in this case use jsonwebtoken for your API and in andriod apps store your token in localstorage and send back token with each request from local storege

Comment: Do I need to store the token in a database? How does the server recognise it?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you need a **WebAPI** - there are **no cookies** nor **sessions** in the API. The only thing that is linking the user from the client code to the backend code is the **JWT**.

You could write your own, but there is no need to since you can find a decent middleware that does exactly that ...  [**`express-jwt`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt)

This will allow you not only to create the `JSON WEB TOKENS` but also to verify them, It is a nice **`Middleware`** and it can solve your issue easily.

This middleware lets you authenticate **HTTP requests** using JWT tokens in your Node.js applications. JWTs are typically used to protect API endpoints, and are often issued using OpenID Connect

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

app.get('/protected',
  jwt({secret: 'your-super shhhhhhared-secret'}),
  function(req, res) {
    if (!req.user.admin) return res.sendStatus(401);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
```